# Pulling Out of the Column Names from a Spark Dataframe built from a HDFS CSV File

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe created from reading a csv file from HDFS.

I have now got a schema on READ as the csv can have different column names at different instances, and the number of columns will vary with different csv files.

How can I pull out only the "column names" from the schema StructType as strings into a separate array or a HashMap.

Regards,
Sanjeeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dataframe, you can call the API columns() which will return the name of the columns as a String array.

[DataFrame (Spark 1.6.3 JavaDoc) - Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#columns())

Comment: @sanjeeb, if it solves your problem, please accept this answer.